# Is there an api for Windows 10 Your Phone App?

Tags: phone

Is there an api for Windows 10 Your Phone App?
I am looking to use my phone as an sms gateway by using Your Phone App. I cannot find any code examples.
Or is there another way to use my phone as sms gateway?

Comment: You should direct your question to the manufacturer of the app.

Answer (score -1):

There is another app that has an api called AirMore. It works similarly to the Your Phone App, as in it lets you send SMS through your phone using your computer and with the api you can automate the process, but I find it harder to connect with the computer, it often fails and takes a long time.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).